# How to implement reservation system in week view in drupal?

Tags: drupal

I want to implement reservation system in my project which should display bookings available for a week (in week view)and users can select the slot which is not booked. I am completely new in drupal. Can anyone tell me how to do this and which module is suitable?

Comment: you can do it using "Views" module, learn how to use views first. :)

Comment: can you explain a little bit or provide a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick in Drupal is to always search for modules that get you closer to what you want, since there are so many that can save you days of work. I would suggest starting by reviewing this comparison of Booking modules:  https://groups.drupal.org/node/137544    before rolling your own.

If none of them suits you, the basic concept would be to have bookings created (a content type) and the some calendar that displays the available dates, then you could use Views for this last part.

The whole solution can be accomplish with a combination of Views and one of the Booking modules above.

Your question is rather general so review that comparison and you will find something you can use for sure.